# devDept Eyeshot - ViewportLayout/Viewport only shows a black screen on application start

Tags: c#, windows, forms, eyeshot

Our windows forms application makes use of devDept Eyeshot for visualization of meshes.
I am getting user reports saying that whenever the application starts and prepares the viewport, only a black screen is presented. Other controls from the UI, such a labels and buttons, display and function correctly.

Of the following image, we should be able to see the left side. Some users report are only seeing the right side.

[Viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxbT1.png)

When dragging the form around, the black screen flickers and it is clear that the viewport is still present behind this black screen.
However, it seems impossible to regain control over the viewport and make it display elements without dragging the form around.

Around 10% of our users encounter this problem, which does make it a significant problem. 
I have tried to replicate the problem on numerous identically set-up virtual machines, where again approximately 10% of VMs have this problem.

I have no further clues on how to get rid of this annoyance, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Solutions tried:
- Updated graphics card driver -> No effect
- Updated BIOS -> Fixes the problem for a few users, but is not a reliable fix
- Resizing or moving the screen seems to solve the problem. However, the viewport seems unstable and sometimes reverts to the 'black-screen' state.

Details:
- version devDept: devDept Eyeshot v9
- builds are made by using Visual Studio 2013

PC configuration(on which this problem occurs):
- x64 builds
- both Debug & Release
- Windows 7 + Windows 10

Comment: Looks like eyeshot (CAD) uses OpenGL and Direct3D which require compatible graphics card, empty black screen means not compatible and no suitable fallback.. You could test for this and display an alert..

Comment: I have a bunch of applications using the control and couple thousands of users and i do not have this issue anywhere. I have the feeling it must be computers without dedicated video card. Try putting `AskForHardwareAcceleration` to `false` on the viewport to force CPU bound OpenGL on these computers.